# CSS fade-in effect for image

Tags: css, fadein

I added a fade-in effect for the logo on a web site:

```
#logo img {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 5s;
    transition: opacity 5s;
}
```

and

```
<div id="logo"><p><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" ... onload="this.style.opacity='1';" /></a></p></div>
```

At first view, it seems to work greatly. But on the second (third, ...) page, the logo is just displayed, it does not fade-in in IE9 or FireFox 19 or Opera 12 - only in Safari 5 and Chrome 25, the fade-in effect is available for every page.

I hardly ever do web design, and that's just a nice to have feature I stumbled upon while playing with CSS. I think it is not appropriate to start learning how to use a big library like jQuery which I would use less than once a year.

Is there a simple method to make it work with the other browsers on all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments this might work:

```
 animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
```

If you want support for IE you should use jQuery.

Comment: I do not use "hover" - the image has to automatically fade-in when the page is shown. Instead of the hover directive, I tried <p><img src="img/logo.png" ... onload="this.style.visibility='visible';this.style.opacity='1';"/></p>, but that had no effect.

Comment: and what if you change -o transition into animation?? like this:       animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */